# Deleted Partition, Stuck in Grub Rescue

Tags: boot, windows-7, grubrescue, partitioning

Long story short, I had Ubuntu pre-installed on my PC. I wanted to replace it with Windows 7, and after a long laborious process, successfully booted up the Windows 7 ISO on my computer with a USB. However, all my partitions were deemed unable to install Windows. To make a long story short even shorter, I deleted some partitions, rebooted, and got stuck on an EFI shell screen. I then typed in the command, "exit", and now I'm stuck in Grub Rescue. I am tired, and I am desperate. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're plan is to completely replace Ubuntu with Windows 7, I would boot up the computer with the Ubuntu live CD (or USB).
Then run GParted and delete all your partitions. Once that's done, run your Windows installation. You should be good to go.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't really help me. I can't access my bios since I'm just shot right into Grub Rescue.

Comment: Some systems then need a full cold boot, or power down, if laptop remove battery, and hold power switch to remove any remaining power. Then immediately boot into BIOS/UEFI. And If drive is gpt Windows will only install in UEFI mode or you have to convert drive to MBR(msdos) to install Windows in BIOS boot mode. Windows 7 can be installed in UEFI boot mode, but may require some updates first.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't helping me at all. I can't boot up the computer with any USB because it just takes me directly to the EFI Shell. Is there anything that I can do to make my computer boot from the USB that I have through the GRUB rescue mode?